# Hexbytes versus python bytes

Tags: solidity, web3.py

I'm trying to find the python analog for the following function

In solidity

```
function getMineDigest(uint256 nonce, bytes32 challenge_digest, bytes32 challenge_number) public view returns (bytes32 digesttest) {
        bytes32 digest = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(challenge_number, msg.sender, nonce));

        return digest;
    }
```

I thought the python analog would be

```
web3.solidityKeccak(['bytes32','address','uint256'], [challenge_number, account, nonce])
```

But when I call the contract from python I get

```
getMineDigest(nonce, challenge_number, challenge_number).call()
output > b'S\x18\x0f\xc1\xf4\x99\\\xb7%N\x12\xf5\x94Ea\xb6\x08\x9a\xe4\x8d\xabD\xb6;#\xe3\xbf\xe9\x01\xef\x1b\xab'
```

And when I run the python analog I get

```
web3.solidityKeccak(['bytes32','address','uint256'], [challenge_number, account, nonce])

output > HexBytes('0xf44ce7626e2cb58df5fec54527ae88e1440661f4544fb5312fa79c35c216e45e')
```

It looks like one is in python bytes and the other is in hexbytes? Is that the only difference?

Comment: What values do you pass for `challenge_number`, `account` and `nonce`?

Comment: In the contract: `uint256 nonce, bytes32 challenge_digest, bytes32 challenge_number`

Comment: In your call to the contract function: `nonce, challenge_number, challenge_number`

Comment: In your call to web3 function: `challenge_number, account, nonce`

Comment: Maybe you should shuffle these parameters a little more, to make it a more difficult challenge for yourself to figure out where you accidentally passed them in the wrong order.

Comment: @goodvibration but the arguments in both hashfunctions should be equivalent: challenger_number, address, nonce, whereas address should be msg.sender in the contract. I think the problem is the address

Comment: BTW, what is the `bytes32 challenge_digest` argument used for in the contract function? Nothing according to what you've posted. I recommend trying to maintain some reasonable amount of order in your code. It might actually help a lot spotting the reasons for your various problems well in advance (or even avoiding them from happening in the first place).

Comment: @sea212: Possibly, but what I'm trying to say is that the code is a mess.

Comment: I agree with you that the code is mess! I'm going to refactor it once I understand what's happening but I'm using [this](https://etherscan.io/address/0xb6ed7644c69416d67b522e20bc294a9a9b405b31#code) contract as reference (see function getMintDigest)

Comment: For account, I'm passing in my metamask public address as a string. I used it earlier to run web3.eth.getBalance(). Should I be converting the type first?

Comment: But yes, that parameter doesn't do anything in the function, that's why I passed it in twice. I just want to make sure I understand [there](https://etherscan.io/address/0xb6ed7644c69416d67b522e20bc294a9a9b405b31#code) contract before I make my own... I think this is a case where I should have refactored it as I was copying

Answer (score 1):

There must be something wrong with the data you provided to both function, the can't be identical. You can test this.

---

Create a contract in [remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/):

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.3;

contract Test {
    function getHash(bytes32 challenge, address adr, uint256 nonce) external pure returns (bytes32) {
        return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(challenge, adr, nonce));
    }
}
```

---

Call the function getHash(...) with the following parameters: `"0x1f1e1d1c1b1a191817161514131211100f0e0c0d0b0a09080706050403020100", "0xCA35b7d915458EF540aDe6068dFe2F44E8fa733c", 42`

Return value of the call: `"0xec8bd2c257c7079fddc12dbd80a9512f07d66f41f52e4ec65d720523e245e88d"`

---

Execute the equivalent python code using web3 (I used `web3.__version__` 5.6.0):

```
from web3 import Web3
Web3.solidityKeccak(['bytes32', 'address', 'uint256'], ["0x1f1e1d1c1b1a191817161514131211100f0e0c0d0b0a09080706050403020100", "0xCA35b7d915458EF540aDe6068dFe2F44E8fa733c", 42])
```

result: `HexBytes('0xec8bd2c257c7079fddc12dbd80a9512f07d66f41f52e4ec65d720523e245e88d')`